# how to set struts <html:select> value in java class

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

I have ShowAction java class, on success of class JSP page will be shown, that jsp page contains

```
<bean:define id="stateTypes" name="sessionData" property="stateTypes"  />
<html:select property="issueStateCode" styleClass="smallDropInput" tabindex="5" styleId="myId">
    <html:options collection="stateTypes" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
</html:select>
```

In my ShowAction java class I am setting values for `<html:select>` (JSP) like this:

```
sessionData.setStateTypes(TypeHelper.getTypeList(TypeHelper.TYPE_JURISDICTION,
            sessionData.getCarrierId(), sessionData.getProductId()));
```

I want to set a particular value from list for `<html:select>` which gets selected or auto populated when JSP will be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution.  `sessionData.getSession().setAttribute("issueBranch","SetValue"); //to set value that you wants to set` and retrive this value in JSP

```
<% String issueBranch= request.getSession().getAttribute("issueBranch").toString(); %>

    <html:hidden styleId="myText" property="issueBranch" value='<%=issueBranch %>' />
```

and set value in JS `var val=document.getElementById('myText').value; 
document.getElementById('myId').value=val; // myId is styleId or id attribute for <html:select>`

Answer (score 1):

The option that will be auto-selected is the option which has the same value as the one returned by the `getIssueStateCode()` method of your form bean, since the `property` attribute of the `<html:select>` tag is `issueStateCode`.

Comment: In your action, call `formBean.setIssueStatusCode(theValueToAutoSelect)`

Comment: Got solution.  `sessionData.getSession().setAttribute("issueBranch","SetValue");` and retrive this value in JSP `<% String issueBranch= request.getSession().getAttribute("issueBranch").toString(); %>
   
 <html:hidden styleId="myText" property="issueBranch" value='<%=issueBranch %>' />` and set value in JS